# How to get reliable x86_64 bit linux systems's memory map

Tags: linux, memory-management, memory-address

I have a very simple program of adding 2 variables written in c. I am executing it in a Linux machine. I want to see all the memory references/virtual addresses that are referenced during the execution of the program. From the program I am getting virtual address (by some means) but I do not know which address belongs to user space and which one belongs to kernel space.

I have used some helpers like (none of them served the purpose):

- Getting memory map of every device in linux : `sudo cat /proc/iomem`
- for more: `sudo cat /proc/vmallocinfo`
- Memory map of a process : `pmap -x pids`
- Memory area of process: `cat /proc/pid/maps`.

For 32 bits, I know Linux uses only 4 segments:

- 2 segments (code and data/stack) for KERNEL SPACE from `[0xC000 0000]` (3 GB) to `[0xFFFF FFFF]` (4 GB)
- 2 segments (code and data/stack) for USER SPACE from `[0x0000 0000]` (0 GB) to `[0xBFFF FFFF]` (3 GB)

But I want to know similar range for 64 bits.

MY code

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(){
int a = 1, b = 2, c; 
 void *ptr;
 c = a + b;
 ptr = malloc(8);
printf("Result %d %p \n", c, ptr);
return 0;
}
```

Bonus: If it possible to know the virtual address for the user code, library space and system/kernel space as well..